# Send request with curl after NTLM auth to same server

Tags: curl, ntlm

I have this command (some values omitted) and it's successfully authenticating.

`curl [URL] -v --ntlm --negotiate -u [username]:[password] -L`

The problem is it comes up with a page after redirecting and I want to use some of the unique values on that page to send a post request. I can't send it in a separate curl command because it'll log me out of my NTLM session. Is there a way to send another request with curl in the same statement so I stay authenticated?

Comment: by default curl tries to keep and reuse connections, are you sure it's not doing this in your case ?

Comment: I have checked and it's not reusing my connection with the next request however when I use `-L` then it does, saying `Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host [URL]`. When it doesn't it sends this at the end of it's execution `Connection #1 to host [URL] left intact`. Is there a way to reuse a connection?

Answer (score 0):

`--next` is your friend! With that you can do multiple different HTTP requests in the same command line. Use it to separate the command line to separate "operations".

Something like this:

```
curl [URL] -v --ntlm --negotiate -u [username]:[password] -L --next \
[URL2] --ntlm --negotiate -u [username]:[password] -d what=sendDatatoServer
```

(I used \ +newline to split the line for display purposes, that should be removed)

Comment: Is there a way for me to send to a different URL?

Comment: uh, there should be another URL after `--next` - I missed to put it there, I've edited the command line now

Comment: Hey Daniel. When I use `--next` with the given redirect instead of following the redirect with `-L` it says I am not authenticated, but when I do follow the redirect it works normally. Is there something `-L` is doing that `--next` can't? Is there a way I can force a redirect?

Comment: I don't have enough info to tell. You're asking (more) questions now in the comments to an answer to a question...